# filename in IE include file path

Tags: internet-explorer

I have below code that has different behavior between IE and others. FileItem.getName() always cannot pass my function for checking invalid filename in IE browser. Others OK!

```
FileItem item =xxxx;
String fileName = item.getName();
IsLegalFileName(fileName);

// it always show invalid file name from below function
public static boolean IsLegalFileName(String str){
        boolean isValid = true;
        int i;

        String[] badChars = {"/","\\",":","*","?","\"" ,"<",">"};

        for (i = 0; i < badChars.length; i++){
            if (str.indexOf(badChars[i]) >= 0)
            {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: Any ideas?? Any Help??